# PHP comparing values received from java

Tags: java, php, mysql, json

so I'm working on this 2 PHP Files, `login.php` and `DB_Functions.php`

there is a specific script in there that is receiving a password and email from the application finding that specific user using the given email and store all the user details in a `$user` array and pass it over to login.php that check if the password entered is correct or not, i've tried hash'ing the password since on the DB its encrypted with 64 BIT.

this is `login.php` (the problem is probably in the `if($user[7] == $password)` which isn't working).

```
 <?php
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {

if($user[7] == $password){
// user is found
$response["error"] = FALSE;
$response["uid"] = $user[0];
$response["user"]["name"] = $user[1];
$response["user"]["email"] = $user[2];
$response["user"]["created_at"] = $user[3];
$response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user[4];
echo json_encode($response);
}else {

// user is not found with the credentials
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Login password credentials are wrong. Please try again!".$checkkk;
echo json_encode($response);
}} else {
// user is not found with the credentials
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
}
?>
```

this is the `DB_Function.php` file ill add only the corresponding functions.

```
/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT unique_id,name,email,created_at,updated_at, encrypted_password , salt FROM users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->store_result();
            $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
            $stmt->bind_result($aid, $aname, $aemail, $acreated_at, $aupdated_at , $aencrypted_password , $asalt);

                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    $user[0] = $aid;
                    $user[1] = $aname;
                    $user[2] = $aemail;
                    $user[3] = $acreated_at;
                    $user[4] = $aupdated_at;
                    $user[5] = $aencrypted_password;
                    $user[6] = $asalt;
                    $user[7] = $this->checkhashSSHA($asalt, $password);
                    }
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            return $user;
            } else {
            return NULL;
            }
    }

/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function isUserExisted($email) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // user exists
        $stmt->close();
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not exists
        $stmt->close();
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}

/**
 * Decrypting password
 * @param salt, password
 * returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
}


}

?>
```

I'm assuming that the problem is at `$user[7] = $this->checkhashSSHA($asalt, $password);` line. 
looking forward for a solution.

Comment: Well if you think that line is the problem... Why don't you `var_dump($user[7]);` and `var_dump($password);` ?

Comment: will that return the value of those vars? and if it will then where would I be able to see it? (a beginner in PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the problem,

```
if($user[7] == $password){
    ...
}
```

You're comparing a hashed password(`$user[7]`) with the user's raw password(`$password`), which doesn't match. First, perform the same hashing as you did in your class method(`checkhashSSHA($salt, $password)`) on raw password, and then compare, like this:

**Solution:**

```
// assuming that checkhashSSHA is public method
$hashed_password = $db->checkhashSSHA($user[6], $password);

if($user[7] == $hashed_password){
    // password match
}
```

**Re-edited:**

```
// assuming that checkhashSSHA is public method
// no need to hash the password again
// $hashed_password = $db->checkhashSSHA($user[6], $password);

// $user[5] contains user's hashed password
// $user[7] contains the hashed password from user's input
if($user[5] == $user[7]){
    // password match
}
```

Comment: well $user[7] is hashed since on DB_Functions its being hashed and sent as the raw password,

Comment: @DanielNetzer `$user[7]` contains hashed password. Look in your DB_Function.php file, `$user[7] = $this->checkhashSSHA($asalt, $password);`. Try the solution I suggested.

Comment: thanks you very much Rajdeep, i just realised that when Hashing a password it doesnt decrypt it, it just make it a readable and comparable key. thanks alot. it works.

Comment: that brought a new issue it seems that doesnt matter what password im entering in the UI the user can login... it seems like they are hashing and comparing the same value from the database.

Comment: which method are you using to hash password? `checkhashSSHA` or `hashSSHA`?

Comment: so on the encrypted password im pulling in from the database im using checkhashSSHA and for the password im getting from the app im doing hashSSHA.

Comment: I think while entering user's details in the database it uses `hashSSHA()` function to hash the password, and it uses `checkhashSSHA()` function to hash user's input password. Please see the **re-edited** section of my answer. It should work now.

Comment: well done Raj. I am still learning the basics behind PHP. nothing is better then doing lots of errors and solving them for 3 days, some alone and some with great people like yourself :D

Comment: Happy to hear. Cheers! :)